# Suitescript that attempts to set an amount for sales order items causes "unexpected error"

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have this code that, in theory, changes the amount on the sublist of a sales order in Netsuite, but for one reason or another it tells me that an unexpected error happened. Nothing I've looked at has been particularly helpful

Edit: To be clear, the error happens when I go to saved mass updates and execute it, not when saving it

```
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType MassUpdateScript
 */
define(['N/record'], (record) => {
    function each(params) {
        let rec = record.load({
            type: params.type,
            id: params.id
        });
      var quant = rec.getValue('custrecordeconomcap');
        rec.setCurrentSublistValue({
        sublistId: 'item',
        filedId: 'quantity',
        value: quant
        });
        rec.save();
    }
    return {
        each: each
    };
});
```

Comment: `setCurrentSublistValue` can only be used when you load the record dynamically.

Comment: Use a `trycatch` block within you function and log the error to get more detailed information about errors in MassUpdateScripts.

Comment: @W.S. Neither changing setCurrentSublistValue to setCurrentValue nor Introducing a trycatch block has resulted in any change or any more information on the subject. To be clear, the problem comes when I execute the script, not when I save it

Comment: You use `setCurrentSublistValue` which is only supported in `dynamic` mode. You load the record in `standard` mode and therefore you should use `setSublistValue`. Doing so, you'll have to provide a line number as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your current code throws an error when calling `setCurrentSublistValue`, so if you would wrap the function body in a `trycatch` block and use the `N/log` module to log the error, you would get more details about the error.

Comment: Error logs can be found on the script deployment page in NetSuite. But for `MassUpdate` and `MassReduce` you've to make sure you catch and log the errors yourself to properly debug.

Comment: I already changed setCurrentSublistValue to setSublistValue, and I already have the try-catch and added 'N/log' on the script. I haven't found any errors in the implementations page, and the error persists

Comment: Update the code in your question according to your recent updates, could be helpful to further advise.

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially a bunch of issues here.

The code doesn't choose a line.

The code appears to assume there is only a single line.

There is a spelling mistake.

Something like this:

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.1
 *@NScriptType MassUpdateScript
 */
define(['N/record'], (record) => {
    function each(params) {
        let rec = record.load({
            type: params.type,
            id: params.id
        });
        var quant = rec.getValue('custrecordeconomcap');
        if (isNaN(quant) || quant < 1) return;
        // if(!quant) return; // if custrecordeconomcap is an integer field

        var targetItemId = 123; // Your target id here
        /* answer assumes only one line item should be updated. 
         * Use your target item. Even if your search for the mass update 
         * filters for orders with the item it pays to be defensive.
         */

        var targetIdx = rec.findSublistLineWithValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'item',
            value: targetItemId
        });

        if (targetIdx == -1) return;

        rec.setSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item',
            fieldId: 'quantity', // OP has filedId
            line: targetIdx,
            value: quant
        });
        rec.save();
    }
    return {
        each: each
    };
});
```